# Why does this Akka Streams application exit abnormally?

Tags: scala, akka, future, akka-stream

I am learning about Akka Streams via the Akka Cookbook module from Packt. I run the [`TransformingStreamsApplication.scala`](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Akka-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter08/src/main/scala/com/packt/chapter8/TransformingStreamsApplication.scala) example and get this:

[image]

To let the actor system exit when the stream processing is completed, I add the following callback:

```
// Future[IOResult]
val future = stream.run()
future.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

But this time the application exits directly without any console output:

[image]

A workaround I came up with is adding `Thread.sleep(10000)`:

[image]

I would like an explanation of this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the stream that you're [referencing](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Akka-Cookbook/blob/master/Chapter08/src/main/scala/com/packt/chapter8/TransformingStreamsApplication.scala):

```
val stream = FileIO.fromPath(path)
  ...
  .to(Sink.foreach(println))
```

Because of the use of the `to` connector, calling `run()` on the above stream returns the materialized value of the source, which in this case is a `Future[IOResult]`. What's happening is that you're terminating the actor system before the stream elements have reached the sink.

Instead of adding a `Thread.sleep`, change the stream to yield the materialized value of the sink, using `toMat` and `Keep.right`. This materialized value is a `Future` as well, and you can terminate the actor system once this `Future` is complete:

```
val stream = FileIO.fromPath(path)
  ...
  .toMat(Sink.foreach(println))(Keep.right)

val future = stream.run()
future.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```

Note that there is a shorthand method for this called `runWith`:

```
val stream = FileIO.fromPath(path)
  ...
  .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))

stream.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())
```